# Accessing settings of an imported VM using VMWare throws "Could not get the dataFileKey" error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

After experiencing a lot of issues regarding lack of snappiness and lagging with a VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine, I decided to switch over to VMware.

As per their [official instructions](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2053864) I performed the following steps:

- Exported virtual machine to an OVA file from VirtualBox
- Imported said OVA file into VMware
- Logged into the VM using VMWare
- Uninstalled VirtualBox guest additions using the commands shown in the video in the link above.

Unfortunately, when I tried to access the settings of the machine to do some basic configuration I got an error:

[image]

I checked the log and the last few lines show the following:

```
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer backtrace[73] frame 0x008fffc4 IP 0x77c7bb1f params 0x103f470 0x7c0000 0 0 [C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll base 0x77c10000 0x0001:0x0006ab1f] RtlClearBits
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer Msg_Post: Error
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer [msg.log.error.unrecoverable] VMware Player unrecoverable error: (vmplayer)
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05)+ vmplayer Exception 0xc0000094  has occurred.
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer [msg.panic.haveLog] A log file is available in "C:\Users\amine\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware-amine\vmware-vmplayer-22428.log".
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer [msg.panic.requestSupport.withoutLog] You can request support.
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer [msg.panic.requestSupport.vmSupport.vmx86]
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05)+ vmplayer To collect data to submit to VMware technical support, run "vm-support".
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer [msg.panic.response] We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
2022-11-19T17:48:31.540Z In(05) vmplayer ----------------------------------------
2022-11-19T17:48:31.571Z In(05) vmplayer CnxFSVigor: Could not get the dataFileKey
```

I did some googling but found no leads as to what might be causing this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for sure. Have you got the original machine?  Can you uninstall VBOX Guest Extensions in Virtual Box?   Then migrate the machine again to VMware.

Comment: Well the official docs as shown in the link I provided explicitly instruct you to *first* export and *then* uninstall the guest extensions once the VM is opened in VMWare. Furthermore, why  do you think uninstalling the guest extensions and then exporting would be any different?

Comment: As I noted, I am not sure, so my suggestion was to try uninstalling first.

Comment: I highly doubt that will solve the problem. What's important is that the VirtualBox guest additions are uninstalled. Whether that happens before or after the import seems quite secondary and unrelated to the error I'm reporting in the OP. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Information I have read about migration to VMware (I use this) is that migration is not assured.  If you cannot migrate, you may need to build a new VMware machine. I have Ubuntu 22.04 running well in VMware

Comment: I will do that as a last resort, but for the time being I would rather attempt to troubleshoot this issue. Great that you have Ubuntu 22.04 running in VMware.

Comment: Try this [workaround](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/VMware-Player-14-Not-loading-Virtual-Machine-Even-After/m-p/945922/highlight/true#M10973).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue,

Edit the VMX file for the VM, and set
virtualHW.version = "20"
to
virtualHW.version = "19"

For some reason when at version 20 , which is VMWare 17, it crashes

Comment: Thank you! It works!!

Comment: Sometimes life is simple :)